# HTML Select Dropdown value not generating when Using clone jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Working on Jquery clone my current code is working for generating new id creating clone ... But what I am not getting is In the first HTML select if I select some option it will get the value of the option and populate to the next box.  But With my current code the clone was happening but when i select the HTML select OPT the value is changing in the original textbox not populating on current text box.

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
<label>School Name</label>
<br/>
<select onchange="getSchoolName(this)" class="slt_Field" id="txt_schName" name="txt_schName"d>
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Emirates College of Technology- UAE">COL000001</option>
    <option value="Al Khawarizmi International College- UAE">COL000002</option>
    <option value="Syscoms College">COL000003</option>
    <option value="Abounajm Khanj Pre-Uni Center">COL000004</option>
    <option value="Advanced Placement">COL000005</option>
    <option value="Al Buraimi College (Uni Clge)">COL000006</option>
    <option value="Al-Ain Community College">COL000007</option>
    <option value="AMA Computer College">COL000008</option>
    <option value="Arab Academy for Bankg and Fin">COL000009</option>
    <option value="ARABACDSCITECHMARTIMETRNS">COL000010</option>
    <option value="Arapahoe Community College">COL000011</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
<br>
<input type="text" class="ipt_Field" name="school_Name" id="school_Name" disabled/>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
   <label><span class="text-error">*</span>High School Avg / CGPA</label>
   <br/>
  <input type="text" class="ipt_Field" id="ipt_Havg" name="ipt_Havg" />
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <label><span class="text-error">*</span>Grade Type @</label>
  <br/>
  <select class="slt_Field" id="ipt_grd" name="ipt_grd">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="n">100</option>
    <option value="n1">4</option>
    <option value="c">CHAR</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/sken4upc/)

Kindly help me

Thanks in advance
Mahadevan

Comment: Hi, the answer for that is easy, you forgot in getSchoolName function that you populate the same element every time. `document.getElementById("school_Name").value = data.value;` same input field every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. Most importantly, if you're going to be cloning and adding elements like this, you should really be using `classes` to access the elements rather than `Ids` that way you don't have to keep up with the number of elements and have a bunch of incremental ids.
2. Next, your js function `getSchoolName(data)` calls `document.getElementById("school_Name").value = data.value;` which means that every time someone changes a select that calls `getSchoolName(data)` you set the selected text to the element with the id `school_Name` rather than the corresponding element. This is fixed by fixing the first issue.
3. You have the class `edu_add_button` on both your `less` and `more` buttons making them BOTH add clones
4. Additionally, you should really bind your functions to the elements rather than doing `onchange="getSchoolName(this)"`.
5. If a user types in a box then adds a new row, the cloned elements will contain all the same text/selections as the elements that were cloned. You should store a copy of the first row on load and use that to make your later clones to avoid that.

This should get you going:

#### [Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sken4upc/4/)

```js
// store a copy of the first row when the page loads
// later, use this copy to make your new elements so the 
// clones dont contain the same text as the cloned elements
$('.cloned-row1:eq(0)').data('stored-clone', $('.cloned-row1:eq(0)').clone())

$(document).on("click", ".edu_add_button", function() {
  var i = $('.cloned-row1').length;
  $('.cloned-row1:eq(0)').data('stored-clone').clone().insertAfter(".cloned-row1:last");
});

$(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function() {
  var len = $('.cloned-row1').length;
  if (len > 1) {
    $(this).closest(".cloned-row1").remove();
  }
});

$(document).on('change', '.txt_schName', function() {
  var cur = $('.txt_schName').index($(this));
  $('.school_Name').eq(cur).val($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid cloned-row1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <label>School Name</label>
      <br/>
      <select class="slt_Field txt_schName" name="txt_schName[]">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="Emirates College of Technology- UAE">COL000001</option>
        <option value="Al Khawarizmi International College- UAE">COL000002</option>
        <option value="Syscoms College">COL000003</option>
        <option value="Abounajm Khanj Pre-Uni Center">COL000004</option>
        <option value="Advanced Placement">COL000005</option>
        <option value="Al Buraimi College (Uni Clge)">COL000006</option>
        <option value="Al-Ain Community College">COL000007</option>
        <option value="AMA Computer College">COL000008</option>
        <option value="Arab Academy for Bankg and Fin">COL000009</option>
        <option value="ARABACDSCITECHMARTIMETRNS">COL000010</option>
        <option value="Arapahoe Community College">COL000011</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <br>
      <input type="text" class="ipt_Field school_Name" name="school_Name[]" disabled/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <label><span class="text-error">*</span>High School Avg / CGPA</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" class="ipt_Field ipt_Havg" id="" name="ipt_Havg[]" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
      <label><span class="text-error">*</span>Grade Type @</label>
      <br/>
      <select class="slt_Field ipt_grd" name="ipt_grd[]">
        <option value="">Please Select</option>
        <option value="n">100</option>
        <option value="n1">4</option>
        <option value="c">CHAR</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn_less1 btn_right ">Less</button>
  <button class="btn_more btn_right edu_add_button">Add More</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update your **getSchoolName** function.

```
function getSchoolName(data) {
    var parentContainer = $(data).closest(".cloned-row1");
    $("input[name='school_Name']",parentContainer).val(data.value);
}
```

I just update your fiddle code. For running code check the [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/eshugoel24/jd4xv7dq/1/)